# Node.js - load and execute multiple functions using Promise.all()

Tags: node.js, promise, anonymous-function, es6-promise

I am developing a "plugins" concept whereby I have a series of files, each containing a single function (a plugin). I would like to automatically load and execute these using `promise.all()`.

Problem: each plugin function does not execute.

Here is my example plugin `plugins/example.js`:

```
"use strict";

exports = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("Plugin running....");
        setTimeout(resolve, 200, 'example plugin succeeded!');
    });
};
```

From my app.js I then load all plugins using the [require-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-all) NPM module:

```
const plugins = require('require-all')(__dirname + '/plugins');
```

I then try to execute all as part of my promise chain:

```
return Promise.all([plugins]);
```

No logging takes place from the function. Interestingly when I log the contents of `plugins`, I see and empty object:

```
{
    "example": {}
}
```

Can anyone advise why the example function is not being called?

Comment: `plugins` is an object with keys and values representing the loaded plugins, and `promise.all` accepts an array of promises, two different things

Comment: You're never actually *calling* the exported function, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RequireAll plugin returns an object containing the plugin name as a key, and the import as the value, so you'll have to get the values and then call those functions to get the promises, and *then* you'd have an array of promises

```
const plugins = require('require-all')(__dirname + '/plugins');

var promises  = Object.keys(plugins).map(function(key) {
    return plugins[key]();
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
    // all done
}).catch(function(err) {
    // fail
});
```

Comment: Fantastic - thanks for the guidance, very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be something like following. Lets say that there is a `plugins` directory with files like `pluginA.js`, `pluginB.js`, ..., `pluginZ.js`. As you stated in your question, exported value from those plugins is always a function that will return a promise. I would create `plugins/index.js` that would export everything from those plugins like:

```
// plugins/index.js
'use strict'

const pluginA = require('./pluginA')
const pluginB = require('./pluginB')
...
const pluginZ = require('./pluginZ')

module.exports = [ pluginA, pluginB, ..., pluginZ ]
```

So then you could use this as following:

```
// foo.js
'use strict'

const _ = require('lodash')
const plugins = require('./plugins')

Promise.all(_.map(plugins, (fn) => fn()))
.then((data) => console.log(data))
.catch((err) => console.log(err))
```